# Nested element's class overridden by parent

Tags: html, css

I'm experiencing a real frustrating CSS Selectivity issue and I'd like to understand why.  Given the following CSS and HTML...

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.5; padding:10px; margin:10px; }

.highlight { background-color:#B9D4FA; color:#000000; }
.contrast { background-color:#3E6FB5; color:#FFFFFF; }

.highlight a:link, .highlight a:visited { color:#3E6FB5; }
.highlight a:hover, .highlight a:active { color:#009900; }

.contrast a:link, .contrast a:visited { color:#FFFFFF; }
.contrast a:hover, .contrast a:active { color: #990000; }
```

```html
<div class="contrast">
<a href="#">CONTRAST LINK</a>
<div class="highlight"><a href="#">HIGHLIGHT LINK</a></div>
</div>
```

(or try at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ecommunities/6t6a8jbm/1/))

**Why is the `HIGHLIGHT LINK` using the styles from `.contrast`?**

The expected behaviour would be that the `HIGHLIGHT LINK` is blue, with a green hover state, NOT white with a red hover state.

They have the same selectivity as far as declaration segment length, and there are no ID's in play at all. I understand that in the end it's because `.contrast` is defined after `.highlight` but my confusion is because in my mind, the `HIGHLIGHT LINK` is a direct decendent of the `.highlight` class and thus *nearer* than `.contrast`.

**NB:** *Please don't suggest using a `>` to get around this, they won't always be direct decendents.*

**EDIT** Let me be clear I understand that the effect is due to the order. My confusion is regarding the selectivity of highlight not being a closer match due to it's proximity.

Let me adjust my question to... **how are you supposed to allow classes to nest and maintain their attributes in situations like these? These *should* be able to nest in either order.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my (rather long-winded) solution ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6t6a8jbm/4/)):

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.5; padding:10px; margin:10px; }

.highlight { background-color:#B9D4FA; color:#000000; }
.contrast { background-color:#3E6FB5; color:#FFFFFF; }

.contrast a:link,
.contrast a:visited,
.highlight .contrast a:link,
.highlight .contrast a:visited { 
    color:#FFFFFF;

}

.contrast a:hover,
.contrast a:active,
.highlight .constrast a:hover,
.highlight .contrast a:active {
    color: #990000;
}

.highlight a:link,
.highlight a:visited,
.contrast .highlight a:link,
.contrast .highlight a:visited {
    color:#3E6FB5;

}

.highlight a:hover,
.highlight a:active,
.contrast .highlight a:hover,
.contrast .highlight a:active {
    color:#009900;
}
```

I think it does what you want it to do, but someone else might be able to do it a little bit more concisely than I have (!).

Comment: I said right in my question that I know that the effect is coming from the order, but my question is about the selectivity of `.highlight' not overriding that of `.contrast` because it's `a` is a nearer decendant.

Comment: @oucil: Sorry, see my edit. I've quoted another answer which explains the way the rules are applied.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve being able to nest these classes in either order, which wasn't clear at first, I've updated the question.  This solution doesn't allow for the reverse.

Comment: @oucil: I've edited my answer with a working solution (I think).

Comment: Thanks, you and I had the same thought at the same time (explicitly defining all nesting orders), I'm testing your solution against a few scenarios now.

Comment: Your's wasn't quite working, I've adjusted, and now it works both ways and reverse. http://jsfiddle.net/ecommunities/6t6a8jbm/8/

Comment: @oucil: Cool, I'm glad I could help. I'd definitely be interested in seeing the end result.

Comment: Sorry posted wrong link above, here: http://jsfiddle.net/ecommunities/6t6a8jbm/8/

Comment: @Oriol You're right, and I did realize that, but figured I could offer three levels of nesting in production which would be enough to reasonably handle any eventuality.  There doesn't seem to be any other viable option due to the lack of a proximity check. It adds a marginal amount of bloat, but in he grand scheme we're talking <1Kb.

Answer (score 0):

You already know that

- The rules have the same [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity)
- Therefore, the applied is the last one

> My confusion is regarding the selectivity of highlight not being a closer match due to it's proximity.

The CSS spec doesn't take your definition of proximity into consideration.

> These *should* be able to nest in either order.

These *could have* been able to nest in either order. But they aren't.

> How are you supposed to allow classes to nest and maintain their attributes in situations like these?

Some ways:

- Use less flexible combinators, such as child combinator `>`
- Know your html and order the CSS rules accordingly
- Use JavaScript

Comment: It was indeed me imagining a 5th check as per proximity, but alas it was only wishful thinking.  That said, the answer I accepted above just explicitly declared the different nesting orders with the correct outcomes and other than causing the declarations to bloat a bit, it works like a charm.